# Parsing JSONP file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I access the Marie-Antoinette.json object in this JSON file? I would like to get the title element of the object but I can't seem to get it to output. Here is my JavaScript code which outputs the object but I cant seem to access the objects elements.

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:5984/movies/efadd5913f5cfd254b2861efd4001cb7',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "JSONP",
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        //async: false,
        success: function(r)
        {
            alert("ok");
            $.each(r, function(index, value){ // iterating over each object
                console.log(index);
                if(index == "_attachments")
                {
                    console.log(value); //how do I output the title ("Marie-Antoinette.json") and the other stuff in the object?
                }

           });
        }
    });
```

Here is the file. The elements I would like to access are in the "_attachments" element of the object.

```
{
    "_id": "efadd5913f5cfd254b2861efd4001cb7",
    "_rev": "6-417588bbff9aa74726b11440a86a8532",
    "_attachments": {
        "Marie-Antoinette.json": {
            "content_type": "application/json",
            "revpos": 2,
            "digest": "md5-Io/Pxakfp/4R8ntjQKWMDg==",
            "length": 761,
            "stub": true
        }
    }
}
```

I think what is throwing me off is that it is an object inside the _attachment section.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ke61kj8j/

Answer (score 0):

The `Marie-Antoinette.json` object is inside your `_attachments` object, but because it contains a `.` it can't be accessed using dot-notation.  You'll have to use array-like notation, passing the key as a string like so:

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response._attachments['Marie-Antoinette.json']);
}
```

If you have multiple "attachments", you can access them in a loop like this:

```
success: function (response) {
    $.each(response._attachments, function (i, attachment) {
        console.log(attachment);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Object.keys` to extract keys from `_attachments` object and then print it:

```
var title = Object.keys(r._attachments)[0];
console.log(title);
```

Or if you have multiple attachments:

```
var titles = Object.keys(r._attachments);
console.log(titles.join());
```

`Object.keys` always returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

in your function:

```
success: function(r)
    {
        for (key in json._attachments) {
          console.log(key); // gives the names
          console.log(json._attachments[key]); // gives the content
        }
    }
```

that would give you the stuff in _attachments